# "undefined is not an object" when trying to access TextInput of the sibling component using references

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in `Parent` component, I'm trying to focus the `TextInput` of second `Child` component when submit button is pressed in the `TextInput` of the first `Child` component but this error comes up: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZasx.png)

Child.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput} from "react-native";

export default class Child extends React.Component {

  focus = ref => {
    ref.input.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='enter text'
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.focus(this.props.destinationRef);
          }}
          ref={input => {
            this.input = input;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent.js

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  //   componentDidMount() {
  //     setTimeout(() => {
  //       this.two.input.focus();
  //     }, 3000);
  //   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Child
          destinationRef={() => {
            if (!this.two) return this.two;
          }}
          ref={input => {
            this.one = input;
          }}
        />
        <Child ref={input => (this.two = input)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Note that when I uncomment the `componendDidMount`, second `TextInput` successfully focuses three seconds after mounting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in render update. In first render time `destinationRef` is undefined, parent state not updated or force updated so props not updated too.

I try little bit optimize your code. You can use arrow function to bind `this`:

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class Parent extends React.Component {

_makeFocus(){
 this.two.input.focus();
}

handleOnSubmit(){
 this._makeFocus();
}

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Child
          onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this)}
          ref={input => {
            this.one = input;
          }}
        />
        <Child ref={input => (this.two = input)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the logic a little bit since I think the ref is giving you problems.

Parent:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Child next={this.two} ref={comp => this.one = comp}/>
        <Child next={this.one} ref={comp => this.two = comp}/>
      </View>
```

Child:

```
<TextInput
          placeholder='enter text'
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            if (this.props.next)
                this.props.next.focus();
          }}
        />
```

EDIT:

Your approach was correct I believe, I would just update the parent into this:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
   super(props);
    this.references = {};
}

  onFocus = (ref) => {
     this.references[ref].focus();
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Child
          destinationRef={'two'}
          onFocus={this.onFocus}
          ref={input => this.references['one'] = input}
        />
        <Child ref={input => this.references['two'] = input} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and your child to:

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='enter text'
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.props.onFocus(this.props.destinationRef);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not working! did it work for you? don't I need to define `ref` tag for `TextInput` in `Child` component?

Comment: Basically, you are passing the component as prop so you would not need the ref inside the child component. Is it throwing any error?

Comment: it's doing nothing. if you omit the `if` statement in `onSubmitEditing` then it will throw an undefined error.

Comment: Right, I think it is because you are trying to solve this from the child itself. See my edit.

Comment: it's not working either. but fortunately I made it work using `connect` in `react-redux`